# Import .prpt file in Pentaho Server using Command Line

Tags: pentaho

I want to upload .prpt (Pentaho Report File) in Pentaho BI Server. I am using the following command:

```
./import-export.sh --import --url=https://server/pentaho/ --username=user --password=pass --source=file-system --type=files --charset=UTF-8 --path=/public--file-path=/home/kishan/folder/Clients/abc/Daily_Reports/Prpt/xyz.prpt --logfile=/home/user/upload.log --permission=true --overwrite=true --retainOwnership=true
```

So, I want to pick up the file located at the file-path value above and upload it to the BI server in the public folder. However, I am getting the following error:

CommandLineProcessor.ERROR_0001 - Missing Arguments: file-path

Why is it saying this even though I have this argument in the command above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Here's the command that worked for me:

**./import-export.sh --import --url=http://localhost:8080/pentaho --username=admin --password=password --charset=UTF-8 --path=/public --file-path=/home/some_directoryN/Daily_Reports/Prpt/xyz.prpt --logfile=/home/kishan/upload.log --permission=true" + "--overwrite=true --retainOwnership=true**

So, for this to work you need the file on the server file system (file-path argument) to which you want to upload the file. path argument is the path on BI server where you want to upload the report